# is there any better way to post my data to mdb since ihave too many values to insert (VB 2010 access DB 2003)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, insert, oledb, ms-access-2003

since as you see below, my 'sql' string is just too long, how can i organize this insert string?
thank you!

```
Try
        conn.Open()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM guests WHERE folio='" & folionum_txtfield.Text & "' AND fname = '" & Fname_txtfield.Text & "'"
        Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

        If Not sqlRead.HasRows Then
            sql = "INSERT INTO guests values (" & folionum & "," & lname & "," & fname & "," & address & "," & lname & "," & country & "," & company & "," & idtype & "," & otherID & "," & idtype & "," & otherID & "," & idnum & "," & otherID & "," & vehicle & "," & vmodel & "," & pnum & "," & rooomnum & "," & datechckin & "," & datechckout & "," & rmtype & numdays & "," & numadults & "," & numchild & "," & notes)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
```

Comment: use parameters it will not only prevent SQL injection attacks, but will make the code more readable.

Comment: Why do say it is too long? I have string that are 1000's of lines long. Is it giving you an error? Is it a DB error or a VB error? It looks "organized" to me. How else do you want to enter the data?

Comment: You could create a class for properties and create a new instance of this ... then you can pass this class in your constructor to your save routine...

Comment: Give me a minute or so and I can give you a little sample...

Comment: @user2721815 I don't agree this isn't organized. I post a solution that would be much better and more organized. He also needs parameters as -@Plutonix mentioned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's some simple steps you can follow to acheive what you would need...**

1. Create a DataClass for ex: GuestDataClass
2. List some properties (setters & getters).
3. Create a new instance of this class and set your properties.
4. Create a function and pass the new instance to your function.
5. Then you can use your properties to save or update etc... as needed.

This won't make it much smaller but more organized.

**Here is a simple example...**

```
 Public Class GuestDataClass 'This would be your new class for your properties...

 #Region "Variables" 'Add your variables here'
   Private strFirstName As String = String.Empty
   Private strLastName As String = String.Empty
 #End Region

 #Region "Properties" 'Add some properties'

 Public Property FirstName() As String
    Get
        Return strFirstName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        strFirstName = value
    End Set
 End Property

 Public Property LastName() As String
    Get
        Return strLastName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        strLastName = value
    End Set
 End Property

 #End Region

 #Region "Methods"

'Inserts new guest'
 Public Shared Function SaveGuest(ByVal oGuest As GuestDataClass) As Boolean

    'Use your properties for the save routine here... just an example...
    'oGuest.FirstName
    'oGuest.LastName 

    Return True
 End Function

 #End Region

 End Class
```

**Then you can use this as such...**

```
 Public Class Form1

 Private pData As GuestDataClass 'Set a variable in your class you can use..

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Set this variable of your data class...
    pData = New GuestDataClass()

    'Set our properties...
    pData.FirstName = "Bobby"
    pData.LastName = "Walters"

    'Save the data...
    If GuestDataClass.SaveGuest(pData) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Saved!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error!")
    End If


End Sub
End Class
```